# Bundle Install runs twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

Bundle install runs twice on Mac

```bash
➜  k_rails_template git:(main) ✗ bundle install
Using Local GEMs
Using Local GEMs <----
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........  <----
Resolving dependencies....
Using rake 12.3.3
.
.
.
```

I have checked the various .zsh configurations to find out if there is something going on there and I have reinstalled a fresh Ruby `2.7.6` using `asdf`.

I manually checked these files to see if there was an issue

- .zshenv
- .zprofile
- .zshrc

## Gem File

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

source 'https://rubygems.org'

gemspec

puts 'Using Local GEMs'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'guard-bundler'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-rubocop'
  gem 'rake', '~> 12.0'
  gem 'rake-compiler', require: false
  gem 'rspec', '~> 3.0'
  gem 'rubocop'
  gem 'rubocop-rake', require: false
  gem 'rubocop-rspec', require: false
end

group :test do
  gem 'simplecov', require: false
end
```

## `gem env`

```bash
gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.1.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.7.6 (2022-04-12 patchlevel 219) [x86_64-darwin21]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/xmen/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/xmen/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/xmen/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/xmen/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/xmen/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/xmen/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-21
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/xmen/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
     - /Users/xmen/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-document"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/xmen/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.6/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin
     - /Users/xmen/.asdf/shims
     - /Users/xmen/.asdf/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /usr/local/go/bin
     - /usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
     - /usr/local/share/dotnet
     - ~/.dotnet/tools
     - /Library/Apple/usr/bin
     - /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
     - /Users/xmen/Library/Python/3.9/bin
     - /Users/xmen/.dotnet/tools
     - /Users/xmen/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/fzf/bin
```

Comment: I don't think that means it's checking rubygems twice or running bundle twice. It generally pops up when you have a pretty complicated Gemfile, meaning lots of interconnected dependencies and few version constraints. I find it better to constrain the versions (if you can) here to speed bundle along.

Comment: Actually, I see what you mean now. What's the need for including the gemspec, too?

Comment: @sam - When developing a gem, use the gemspec method in your Gemfile to avoid duplication. In general, a gem's Gemfile should contain the Rubygems source and a single gemspec line. https://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/

Comment: Double `puts` is normal, bundler just evals Gemfile twice [1](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/bundler-v2.3.16/bundler/lib/bundler/dsl.rb#L12) [2](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/bundler-v2.3.16/bundler/lib/bundler/plugin.rb#L106). If I use your Gemfile (without gemspec) I get a second "Fetching" with only one dot upto bundler v2.2.6. `v2.2.7` just a single fetch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bundle install` is not running twice. It is the internal bundler logic that does the second fetch.

```
# Gemfile

source "https://rubygems.org"
gem "guard-bundler"
```

For example, using bundler *v2.2.6* the above *Gemfile* will make bundler run two fetch requests.

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..............
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
```

The second request comes from double checking logic:

*https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/bundler-v2.2.6/bundler/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb#L261*

Surprisingly, the second fetch was double checking for *bundler* gem itself. [This](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/pull/4308) pull request [fixed](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/commit/bd9dff35f6f54bc6c7123fe6ae5329ef1d0ae9b5#diff-828acea145b306f0a63d5e01a096fa2fcd7d97aceeeb0f8922120e661c30c338L140) that in *v2.2.7*.

Upgrading to bundler *v2.2.7* issues only a single request. However, with more gems in the *Gemfile* there will be more to double check for bundler. I'd assume there are more performance/logic improvements with later versions as well.

You can see why bundler is running a second fetch by using `--verbose` option:

```
$ bundle update --verbose
...
Double checking for ["bundler"] in rubygems repository https://rubygems.org/ or installed locally
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Looking up gems ["bundler"]
...
```